# How to add line breaks to $email['body'] when using auto_core_update_email hook

Tags: email, wp-mail, automatic-updates

I am using the auto_core_update_email hook to modify the auto update email sent by WordPress.  However I cannot figure out how to add line breaks to  the email body.  Here's my code:

```
function example_filter_auto_update_email($email) {
    $email['to'] = array('example@example.com', 'test@example.com');
    $email['subject'] = 'Auto Update';
    $email['body'] = 'Hello,%0D%0A'
      . 'Lorem ipsum.%0D%0A'
      . 'Many thanks,%0D%0A'
      . 'WordPress';

    return $email;
}

add_filter('auto_core_update_email', 'example_filter_auto_update_email', 1);
```

I have also tried using:
 `<br />`, `\r\n`, as well as `%0D%0A`, seen above.  However, in each case the string is just printed in my email client like this:

Hello%0D%0ALorem Ipsum%0D%0AMany thanks%0D%0AWordPress

How can I get line breaks printed in my auto update emails?  If it helps the emails are being sent by SMTP.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use single quotes with escape sequences like  `\r`, `\n` and so on. Use double quotes:

```
$a = 'Hello, ' . "\n";
$b = "Good Bye, \n";
```

See [Double quoted strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using `"\n"`, you could also use PHP's end of line constant: `PHP_EOL`

```
    $email['body'] = 'Hello,%0D%0A' . PHP_EOL
  . 'Lorem ipsum.%0D%0A' . PHP_EOL
  . 'Many thanks,%0D%0A' . PHP_EOL
  . 'WordPress';
```

Comment: keep in mind that `PHP_EOL` !== `"\n"` depending on the platform in which the email is sent from and the one on which it is being read. Most likely it does not have an impact in modern email software, but worth keeping it in mind.

Comment: yes probably best to stick with "\n" for email then.